# Where are gnome-terminal profiles stored on a Linux distribution?

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, profile

I have used (Red Hat, Ubuntu, CentOS, others). These distributions utilize Gnome-terminal, and provide flexible ways to set up different terminal profiles via a drop down menu located in the terminal window, directly above where commands are, usually, entered. These profiles allow making changes to the font and color properties of different files etc..

Where are these different profiles for the terminal stored?

Answer (score 7):

On my Ubuntu 16.04,

- open dconf editor (as the user)
- org > gnome > terminal > legacy > profiles > ...

Comment: Looks like these are somehow stored without schema, so I can't automatically set profiles from the command line (`gsettings set`), any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've just cited three distributions that use at least two different `Gnome` versions. This is important because of the move from `Gnome 2` to `Gnome 3` which moved from `GTK 2` to `GTK 3` and mixed things a little.

To get to his topic, generally, all your configuration for your user are in `$HOME` somewhere. First you need to look in `$HOME` itself and then try `.config` and `.gconf` as both suggest a configuration directory.

That being said and with a simple google search I found that it might be in `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles` but your milage may vary.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. `GTK` version will affect `gtk-2.0` and `gtk-3.0` directory configuration though. I was talking in general and not just gnome-terminal.